# Secure data per user using contentful

Tags: database, security, oauth, user-data, contentful

I want to be able to manage users in contenful, every user has some data (files, text, etc) that should only be able te be accessed by this specific authenticated user.

In firebase for example this would be possible by using database rules, but would something similar be possible in contentful?

ps: I try to avoid writing custom backend for this.

Answer (score 0):

As you say you would not like to write custom backend code.

If you are calling the Contentful API on the client side instead of a backend server calling Contentful, the Authorisation keys will be exposed allowing anyone to scan through all the Contentful User data.

It may not be the ideal CMS for your use case.